# Adding GCC compiler to Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, gcc, eclipse-cdt

How can I add GCC compiler to the Eclipse IDE?

Thanks.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure the [CDT package](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers-includes-incubating-components/indigor) for eclipse uses GCC. There may be some additional installation required if you're using Windows, such as installing [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) with the GCC compiler.